# Fuse wire partially fried, is it just what im assuming is the soldering?

Tags: electrical, wiring, soldering

Is some kind of soldering at fault? Im assuming that since the wire further back is clean.
The fuse itself is not broken.
Does this indicate something worse internally broken?
Should i re solder or wire it? Or will the same issue occur?

Its an milling machine. Holzmann bf20v. Could grease of some form made it there?

I have already contacted them for spare parts in vain several times and im to embarrased to contact them again ;_;. And this doesnt look like an expensive thing to fix.

[image: How the wire was connected]
[image: Fried wire]
[image: Fried contactor]
[image: Clean wire after i cut the wire slightly behind]

Comment: There is nothing even vaguely identifiable in those pics and they help with the understanding of the question. If you're embarrassed about having called them, well, that's life. Pull that part out of the question if you don't want people to know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would at minimum replace the fuse holder, they are avaiable at several online retailers, digikey, mcmaster carr, grainger etc.

If it got hot enough to melt the solder theres a chance the holder is damaged internally, they should be less than $10 for the panel mount holder.